# D3 text positioning inside g element

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am new to D3 and I am trying to add text inside rectangle using D3 v5. I have written following code for same.

```
rootSVG = d3.select('.rootSVG')
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', (d, i, elements) => {
        return 'translate(0, ' + i * 21 + ')';
    });

rootSVG.append('rect')
    .attr('height', 20)
    .attr('width', 100)
    .style('fill', 'green')
    .on('mouseover', (d, i, elements) => {
        d3.select(elements[i])
           .transition()
           .duration(500)
           .style('fill', 'red');
    })
    .on('mouseout', (d, i, elements) => {
        d3.select(elements[i])
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style('fill', 'green');
    });

rootSVG.append('text')
    .attr('x', 10)
    .text((d, i, elements) => {
         return d.name;
    });
```

I am getting the following results in the browser.
[image]
As you can see in above picture, rectangle elements are getting placed fine but text elements are off. Why this behaviour is happening even though they belong to same group? How to I make sure that text always stays inside the rectangle?

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ysm0hfzn/4/

Comment: can you upload the code to jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/ysm0hfzn/4/

Comment: Thanks, do you any css with that?

Comment: No css needed. Only Javascript and HTML

Comment: in the jsfiddle you uploaded the text is in the right place inside the rect element

Comment: the `Number` text should be inside 2nd rectangle. https://i.imgur.com/wpZJ4Af.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to how SVG draws text.

It's somewhat different from playing with divs and all in "traditional" HTML: you could think of it as an actual **graphics** framework.

---

The problem here is that the `text` element's **baseline** is, by default, its **bottom edge**. Which means that, when drawing text at `(0, 0)`, the `text` element's **bottom-left** corner will be at `(0, 0)`

You could change your `text` elements' dominant baseline by adding the following CSS to your code:

```
g > text {
    dominant-baseline: text-before-edge;
}
```

This would allow your `text`s to be drawn **inside** your `g`s, vertically.

---

As a side note, the horizontal-axis equivalent of the baseline for text is determined by the `text-anchor` property. If you wanted to **center** your text inside their `g`, you could simply:

1. **anchor** the `text` elements in to their `middle`: `text-anchor: middle`
2. center the anchor within your `g`: `x="50"`

---

Here's a code snippet demonstrating how to use the properties I mentionned in your example.

```css
g > text {
  dominant-baseline: text-before-edge;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g>
    <rect width="100" height="20" fill="LimeGreen"></rect>
    <text x="50">Letter</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0, 22)">
    <rect width="100" height="20" fill="LimeGreen"></rect>
    <text x="50">Number</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and helping me out.